# Ati - Problems with open drivers after fglrx remove

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, opengl

I have ubuntu 12.04 and kde 4.10.1.
I have removed fglrx drivers 13.1 doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

I have also removed xorg.conf (it was in a guide)

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and then I did

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

After reboot I have kde plasma-desktop crash every time and the Resolution is 1280x1024 but my maximum right resolution is 1920x1080 and I can't change it in kde settings menu.
I cannot use opengl in kde effects menu and so no effects.

Same resolution problem with any other desktop (unity 3d/2d and gnome classic).

The output of

```
glxinfo | grep render

direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend
```

The output of:

```
glxinfo | grep -i opengl

OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

here is my Xorg.0.log:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mPxeD99w

I have also added ppa "ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates" and upgrade my system, but it did not solve the problem.

My machine specs:

- gpu: msi/ati r6870 hawk
- cpu: i5-2500k sandy bridge
- motherboard: P8P67 PRO

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge virtualbox because it causes the issue with the KDE effects since llvmpipe driver is blacklisted for them. For some reason, the virtualbox's driver is used after uninstalling fgrlx.

I guess it should also help with the resolution too.

Sergey

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help me, I removed virtualbox and rebooted, I still have low resolution and plasma crash at startup and "glxinfo | grep -i opengl" gives me same output.